# How to Write a function that will return the value of the array element which does not have a matching pair?

Tags: arrays, match

I'd like to ask for a help regarding the function which has to return a value of the array element which does not have a matching pair.

For instance,

a) In the array [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4], the element without a pair is 2.

b) In the array [1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], the element without a pair is 4.

So far I come up with the code below. So basically it checks for the repetitive numbers, and thus works for the b) case; yet it doesn't works for the a) case. Any help regarding how to fix this code, so that it works for a) and b) cases, is welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int     ft_unmatch(int *tab, int length)
    {
      int i;
      int j;
      int count;

      i = 0;
      while (i < length)
        {
          j = i + 1;
          count = 0;
          if (tab[i] == tab[j])
            {
              count++;
              while (j < length)
                 {
                  if (tab[i] == tab[j])
                    count++;
                 j++;
                 }
          if (count % 2 != 0)
              return (tab[i]);
           }
          i++;
        }
      return (tab[i]);
    }


    int     main(void)
    {
      //some additional arrays to check the function
      int tab[9] = {1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4};
      //int tab[11] = {1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4};
      // int tab[7] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4};
      printf("%d\n", ft_unmatch(tab, 9));
      return (0);
    }
```

Comment: What results are you getting when it is "not working"?

Comment: Sort, then scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all elements in the array are integer numbers and have a matching pair except one, just keep XORing the elements until the last one. Your result at the end of the scan will be the unmatched element.

The reason why this works is that:

- XOR is commutative (so `a XOR b = b XOR a`)
- for every a, `a XOR a = 0`
- for every a, `0 XOR a = a`

Every element will be cancelled out by their matching pair except one: the one you are looking for.

example:

```
int result=0;
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result = result ^ tab[i];
}
return result;
```

Then handle edge cases as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems in this code:

You compare every number with all of the following ones. So in a), you compare the first 1 with all the other numbers and count two 1s, but then you count the second 1 again and won't find another, so you code returns 1.

Also, you are missing curly brackets following the `if tab[i] == tab[j])` and you only get to the `while(j<length)`-loop if the first `if(tab[i] == tab[j]`is true.

One possible solution would be to remove the numbers that were already counted from the array, so you don't count them again, or sort the array and count until each increment. If you are only working with small numbers you could also iterate over every possible number and count how often it appears, although that would be less elegant.